# Is it possible to make a Java method transactional?

Tags: java

For a project I am building a stand-alone Java application. At a point I want to insert data into several database tables. These insert statements are all called from one method, and all have their own Java class which contains the code to execute the statements. Something like this:

```
DataService1 ds1 = new DataService1();
DataService2 ds2 = new DataService2();

updateDatabase() {
  ds1.insertData1(data);
  ds2.insertData2(data2);
}
```

The class `DataService1` and `DataService2` are classes that connect to the database and execute the insert statements.

Is it possible to make this method (`updateDatabase()`) transactional? That if one of the inserts into the table fails, that the method rolls back all other sql statements? I know you can make sql statements transactional, but the insert statements are all in different classes.
Or is my approach wrong in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: your insertData methods should have a boolean return value. If one of them returns false you should roll back all inserts done before... You'll have to code what you want to have! Java can't know what you define as transactional therefore it can't revert any changes you made!

Comment: You could get a TransactionManager and handle the same manager to each method. As a last call you try to commit/close the transaction and rollback it in case of an exception.

Comment: Things like JPA have annotations like `@Transactional` to do exactly that. Under the hood, this still needs to come down to managing database transactions, though. No magic here.

Comment: What is the technology stack that you are using? The Java EE stack provides the `@Transactional` annotation, that does just what you need. It is also available in the Spring framework.

Comment: @ParkerHalo: Exceptions seem to be a much better way to handle failed statements than boolean return values.

Comment: Don't forget that it is a standalone application, not a web application. No frameworks as Spring are available, so I think @Transactional will not be available to me.
I can't seem to find TransactionManager, is it a separate library that I can import?

Comment: You can use Spring in standalone applications too.

Comment: You can? I never realized that. Time to investigate this possiblity then!

Comment: This is a good start https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncih.html

Comment: So, if I rebuild my application and make use of Hibernate and/or Spring, I will very easily solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a try-catch for this. Make ds1 and ds2 attempt to insert it, and if it fails use `throw new MyInsertFailedException()` (you'd have to make that one, it's just a class that extends Exception.) In the `catch (MyInsertFailedException e){}` you can then apply the code that makes each DataService attempt to roll back.

Comment: ... and you need to make your DataServices use the same Connection somehow (this is how you control the transaction).

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible. You just need to make sure you open a transaction at the beginning of the method, use that transaction for your statemets and if one of the statements fails you rollback the transaction.

ORM systems such as Hibernate can handle this for you automatically.